# Implementing CV2 compareHist

Tags: python, statistics, opencv, chi-squared

Im trying to compare two discrete histograms grouped by as following -

```
bins    freq
0      1000
1      200
2      100
3      400
...    ...
```

Both histograms are holding the above structure with different freq. values.
I can't figure out how to implement CV2 compare histograms function - mostly facing issue with the inputs
What should be the structure of each histogram so it would be comparable ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give an example of the expected output? Minimal reproducible example would also help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure. I would like to get the estimated chi square of the comparison